# How to implement basic SIMD operations on a custom struct in Rust?

Tags: rust, simd

I have a struct:

```
#[repr(simd)]
struct Vec4 {
    x:f32, y:f32, z:f32, w:f32
}
```

How do I implement basic SIMD operations like `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` on it?

Am I limited to using only the predefined types like `f32x4` from the experimental `simd` crate?

Comment: Hint: a SIMD vector is usually not a good choice for representing a single x,y,z coordinate vector.  You usually end up needing a lot of horizontal operations if you try to use SIMD that way.  See the [these slides from a talk](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/), and other links in the [sse tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info).  As far as SIMD in Rust, IDK.

Comment: Thanks for interesting papers. So the simd classes is not good idea at all?

Comment: It depends what you use it for.  SIMD is great if you can arrange your data so you can load a vector of 4 `x` values, another vector of 4 `y` values, etc.  Then you can do operations on 4 vectors at once.  If you can't do they, you *might* be able to still get some minor benefit, or a big benefit but only for a few functions.